# CREATE_LAYER_FUNC cocos 2dx -- error

Tags: java, android, c++, cocos2d-x

Can someone tell me how to fixx this error?

```
jan@home:~/bin/cocos2dx/CocosTest/proj.android$ ./build_native.sh
NDK_ROOT = /home/jan/bin/android-ndk-r8d
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /home/jan/bin/cocos2dx/CocosTest/proj.android/../..
APP_ROOT = /home/jan/bin/cocos2dx/CocosTest/proj.android/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /home/jan/bin/cocos2dx/CocosTest/proj.android
Using prebuilt externals
make: Entering directory `/home/jan/bin/cocos2dx/CocosTest/proj.android'
Compile++ thumb  : game_shared <= main.cpp
In file included from jni/hellocpp/main.cpp:6:0:
jni/../../Classes/DoYourJobScene.h:10:30: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'LAYER_CREATE_FUNC' with no type [-fpermissive]
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/hellocpp/main.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/jan/bin/cocos2dx/CocosTest/proj.android'
jan@home:~/bin/cocos2dx/CocosTest/proj.android$
```

here the Source: http://jandroid.ch/CocosTest.tgz

Comment: post the code for LAYER_CREATE_FUNC

Comment: PS: your title says CREATE_LAYER_FUNC … you sure this isn't a simple typo?

Comment: COCOS2DX_ROOT = /home/jan/bin/cocos2dx     ....also it should be CREATE_FUNC if new cocos2d-x

Answer (score 0):

LAYER_CREATE_FUNC and SCENE_CREATE_FUNC can be replace by one macro CREATE_FUNC
[See this!](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/issues/1442)

So you should know how to do it.